# Make TS put all source files, including non-TS, into the build directory

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

My folder structure is the following:

```
src
└> index.ts
└> image.webp
└> test.html
└> something.css
build
└> index.js
tsconfig.json
```

As you may see, in my build folder, there is only the built index File, but not my WEBP, HTML and CSS files, which I want to be in the build folder though.
Is there a way to do that?
My current tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6",
      "removeComments": true,
      "typeRoots": ["@types"],
      "outDir": "build"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": ["src"]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible with tsconfig

You could try to write a build script with `copyfiles`

```
"build": "npm-run-all build:*",
"build:lib": "tsc",
"build:asset": "copyfiles image.webp test.html some.css build",
```

You could also achieve the same with `webpack` and `CopyPlugin`

Comment: Like how the website you linked, says that that only allows _JavaScript_ files, which is not what I want...

Comment: my apology, i misunderstood

Comment: I believe it is not possible with tsconfig, you can either use package like `copyfiles` or use bundler like `webpack`

Answer (score 1):

This has a solution by [@bencergazda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111787/bencergazda), he has created [typescript-cp](https://github.com/body-builder/typescript-cp) that works exactly like you would have hoped.

It works in parallel with typescript and it reads your tsconfig.

I installed it globally on my machine as it [is available on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-cp) and just ran "tsc" to do the initial copy build, then I add script with "tsc -w && tscp -w" to have typescript work in parallel with typescript-cp.

Comment: Your solution did not work. I got the this "Error: No 'rootDir' configured in reference ''". I'm using typeORM